# Android CameraX YuvToRgbConverter artefacts

Tags: android, rgb, yuv, android-camerax

I am trying to implement CameraX into an APP. So far I have managed to do this but I have 2 problems.

1. I used the YuvToRgbConverter from [this](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/3730442b49189f76a1083a98f3acf3f5f09222a3/CameraUtils/lib/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera/utils/YuvToRgbConverter.kt) official repository, however, I am getting the image with some artifacts
2. The image after processing that you see in the bottom right corner has a different orientation than that in the preview.

On the `ImageAnalysis` I have tried to put different `.setTargetrotation` but the result is the same whatever I change.

```
        val imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .setTargetRotation(Surface.ROTATION_0)
            .build()
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

[image]

The code that is handling the conversion looks like this:

```
class YuvToRgbConverterServiceImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context
) : YuvToRgbConverterService {

    private val rs = RenderScript.create(context)
    private val scriptYuvToRgb = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs))

    private var pixelCount: Int = -1
    private lateinit var yuvBuffer: ByteBuffer
    private lateinit var inputAllocation: Allocation
    private lateinit var outputAllocation: Allocation

    override fun convertYuvToRgb(image: Image): Bitmap {
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.width, image.height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        yuvToRgb(image, bitmap)
        return bitmap
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun yuvToRgb(image: Image, output: Bitmap) {

        // Ensure that the intermediate output byte buffer is allocated
        if (!::yuvBuffer.isInitialized) {
            pixelCount = image.cropRect.width() * image.cropRect.height()
            // Bits per pixel is an average for the whole image, so it's useful to compute the size
            // of the full buffer but should not be used to determine pixel offsets
            val pixelSizeBits = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
            yuvBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pixelCount * pixelSizeBits / 8)
        }

        // Rewind the buffer; no need to clear it since it will be filled
        yuvBuffer.rewind()

        // Get the YUV data in byte array form using NV21 format
        imageToByteBuffer(image, yuvBuffer.array())

        // Ensure that the RenderScript inputs and outputs are allocated
        if (!::inputAllocation.isInitialized) {
            // Explicitly create an element with type NV21, since that's the pixel format we use
            val elemType = Type.Builder(rs, Element.YUV(rs)).setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.NV21).create()
            inputAllocation = Allocation.createSized(rs, elemType.element, yuvBuffer.array().size)
        }
        if (!::outputAllocation.isInitialized) {
            outputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output)
        }

        // Convert NV21 format YUV to RGB
        inputAllocation.copyFrom(yuvBuffer.array())
        scriptYuvToRgb.setInput(inputAllocation)
        scriptYuvToRgb.forEach(outputAllocation)
        outputAllocation.copyTo(output)
    }

    private fun imageToByteBuffer(image: Image, outputBuffer: ByteArray) {
        assert(image.format == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)

        val imageCrop = image.cropRect
        val imagePlanes = image.planes

        imagePlanes.forEachIndexed { planeIndex, plane ->
            // How many values are read in input for each output value written
            // Only the Y plane has a value for every pixel, U and V have half the resolution i.e.
            //
            // Y Plane            U Plane    V Plane
            // ===============    =======    =======
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    U U U U    V V V V
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            val outputStride: Int

            // The index in the output buffer the next value will be written at
            // For Y it's zero, for U and V we start at the end of Y and interleave them i.e.
            //
            // First chunk        Second chunk
            // ===============    ===============
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y    V U V U V U V U
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            // Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y
            var outputOffset: Int

            when (planeIndex) {
                0 -> {
                    outputStride = 1
                    outputOffset = 0
                }
                1 -> {
                    outputStride = 2
                    // For NV21 format, U is in odd-numbered indices
                    outputOffset = pixelCount + 1
                }
                2 -> {
                    outputStride = 2
                    // For NV21 format, V is in even-numbered indices
                    outputOffset = pixelCount
                }
                else -> {
                    // Image contains more than 3 planes, something strange is going on
                    return@forEachIndexed
                }
            }

            val planeBuffer = plane.buffer
            val rowStride = plane.rowStride
            val pixelStride = plane.pixelStride

            // We have to divide the width and height by two if it's not the Y plane
            val planeCrop = if (planeIndex == 0) {
                imageCrop
            } else {
                Rect(
                    imageCrop.left / 2,
                    imageCrop.top / 2,
                    imageCrop.right / 2,
                    imageCrop.bottom / 2
                )
            }

            val planeWidth = planeCrop.width()
            val planeHeight = planeCrop.height()

            // Intermediate buffer used to store the bytes of each row
            val rowBuffer = ByteArray(plane.rowStride)

            // Size of each row in bytes
            val rowLength = if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
                planeWidth
            } else {
                // Take into account that the stride may include data from pixels other than this
                // particular plane and row, and that could be between pixels and not after every
                // pixel:
                //
                // |---- Pixel stride ----|                    Row ends here --> |
                // | Pixel 1 | Other Data | Pixel 2 | Other Data | ... | Pixel N |
                //
                // We need to get (N-1) * (pixel stride bytes) per row + 1 byte for the last pixel
                (planeWidth - 1) * pixelStride + 1
            }

            for (row in 0 until planeHeight) {
                // Move buffer position to the beginning of this row
                planeBuffer.position(
                    (row + planeCrop.top) * rowStride + planeCrop.left * pixelStride)

                if (pixelStride == 1 && outputStride == 1) {
                    // When there is a single stride value for pixel and output, we can just copy
                    // the entire row in a single step
                    planeBuffer.get(outputBuffer, outputOffset, rowLength)
                    outputOffset += rowLength
                } else {
                    // When either pixel or output have a stride > 1 we must copy pixel by pixel
                    planeBuffer.get(rowBuffer, 0, rowLength)
                    for (col in 0 until planeWidth) {
                        outputBuffer[outputOffset] = rowBuffer[col * pixelStride]
                        outputOffset += outputStride
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not tell us how do you use the function. Note: there are many yuv, and many rgb, try to find if you are using the right function (linear or gamma corrected? full or limited range? [first common in computer, the second in video], and which colour space). In any case, it seems you got also something from on how you create the result (e.g. memory matrix: there are two different convention: FORTRAN and C indexing). And are you sure initial image was YCC? (colour space is different then image format)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I have edited the question and added the code.

Comment: I'm missing where you do the conversion (you do a lot of preparation to prepare YUV buffer). Are you sure you have the correct type of Bitmap? (you may need 4 bytes, order is usually not R,G,B). I think you need debugging. Try with some defined images (and maybe on your desktop). Save the different step and check if they seems correct. Run in in a debugger. Possibly it is just a wrong index somewhere, but difficult to debug just by reading the code